# Shorthand for assignment if zero, like c = str[i] || 'x'

Tags: c, char, boolean

*(This is a very basic question, but I can't seem to find an answer because it involves `||`, which is a problematic search term.)*

Since a char can be interpreted as a boolean in a conditional like this:

```c
if (str[i]) ...  
if (c) ...
```

where '\0' is considered falsey and any other character is truthy, I was expecting this to work too:

```c
char c = str[i] || 'x';
```

but it's always giving a value of 1. Is there a simple shorthand in C for this? I've become used to it in JavaScript, and I find it clear and concise.

Comment: Use the ternary operator.

Comment: About the shortest you're going to get is `char c = str[i] ? str[i] : 'x';`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I was hoping to avoid repeating str[i], but I guess the overhead is only visual, and therefor unimportant.

Comment: The problem is that JS handles boolean expressions fundamentally different. It only works because in JS, any expression can be coerced into a boolean. In C, this is simply not the case.

Comment: @IngoBürk - Depends what you mean.  In C, anything that equates to 0 is effectively equivalent to `FALSE` in relevant situations (i.e. `if`, operands to boolean operators, conditional operator).  That applies to all types.

Comment: the `||` returns either 1 (if either operand is true) or 0 (if both are false), and it's that returned result you're assigning to `c`.  You *could* do `char c; (c = str[i]) || (c = 'x');`, but that would do `c = str[i]` regardless of its value and follow with `c = 'x'` only if it was false.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/16925429/583456 for a link to GCC extension which allows for `char c = str[i++] ?: 'x';`.

Comment: What was the problem getting a list of C operators and learning what the `||` operator means? Best would be, of course to get a C book. Seraching for `||` is definitively not the only way! Any reason you expect two very different languages behave the same?

Comment: @Olaf Well, I read "C Primer Plus" in 1996, but that's a long time ago, and I haven't used C much since.

Comment: @m69: The meaning of that operator has noit changed much. Though you should read a more recent book. Anyway, you apparently did no research on your own.

Comment: Well here I was thinking I'd do someone a favour by adding a code example to an answer; I won't be doing that again anytime soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle it like any other abstraction, and write a function for it:

```
char non_zero_or_default(const char c, const char d)
{
    return c ? c : d;
}
```

then use it as:

```
char c = non_zero_or_default(str[i++], 'x');
```

You can `inline` it if you're worried about overhead.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator is what you are looking for:

```
char c = str[i] ? str[i] : 'x';
```

Exaplanation: if `str[i]` is truthy, assign value of `str[i]` to variable `c`, other case assign letter `'x'`.

Comment: Thanks; any idea what to do with `c = str[i++] || 'x'`?

Comment: I assume that it works like in PHP, where `'x'` would be treated as truthy value, so `[whatever] OR true -> true`. That's why you get `1` (true in C).

Comment: I meant what to do with the index increment; both `char c = str[i++] ? str[i] : 'x'` and `char c = str[i] ? str[i++] : 'x'` do something different than `c = str[i++] || 'x'`. (But I guess that's another question.)

Comment: So, you want to always increment the value of `i`. Maybe something like this (it looks a little bit stupid, but if you want to do it in one line...): `var c= str[i++] ? str[i-1] : 'x';`

Comment: Please don't actually write that :(

Comment: Yeah, I know :) just wanted to show, that's possible

Comment: @dzej.5: That has undefined behavior of `i++` overflows.

Comment: Yup, I regret that I wrote that line :)